# Dynamic Lat Lang inside a MapView in react-native

Tags: google-maps, react-native, android-mapview, expo

Am using `expo` `MapView`.and i'm searching solution for How to find lat and land with respect to the phone's height and width .*Ex* :  `[ [lat, lang],[lat, lang],[lat, lang],[lat, lang] ]` . [image: here i attached the screenshot]

Can someone help/clarify me pls .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a region object from `MapView` via `onRegionChange` or any other similar event, that object contains 4 properties.

**Example**

```
const region = {
  latitude: 37.78825,
  longitude: -122.4324,
  latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
  longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
}
```

Delta values are for difference between the minimum and maximum points that you want displayed.

*(Image from [MKMapView and Zoom Levels: A Visual Guide](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/mkmapview-and-zoom-levels-a-visual-guide/))*

[image: example of delta points]

With this information you can calculate the 4 corners of the MapView (map bounds) or you can use them to set the level of zoom.

**Example** *(Not tested so there might be some error on calculation)*

If we set our `MapView` on region given in the example below, our four corners will be the positions calculated below.

```
const leftTopLongitude = region.longitude - (region.longitudeDelta / 2);
const rightTopLongitude = region.longitude + (region.longitudeDelta / 2);
const leftTopLatitude = region.latitude + (region.latitudeDelta / 2);
const rightTopLatitude = region.latitude + (region.latitudeDelta / 2);

const leftBottomLongitude = region.longitude - (region.longitudeDelta / 2);
const rightBottomLongitude = region.longitude + (region.longitudeDelta / 2);
const leftBottomLatitude = region.latitude - (region.latitudeDelta / 2);
const rightBottomLatitude = region.latitude - (region.latitudeDelta / 2);
```

Comment: Amazing bro , It just works like a Charm . Thnx a ton bro :)

Comment: My state values and Props values are undefined inside `onRegionChange` method . .!! i can't able to call any method also . . .why ? what's the reason ?

Comment: @Becky first of all, calm down. You don't need that much exclamation points. Secondly your problem is related to context of `this`. You need to bind your functions to use `this` in them. [Read this page carefully](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events)